# mautic throws error php error during installation on aws ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, cloudflare, mautic

mautic throws amazing error during installation :

> The site is currently offline due to encountering an error. If the problem persists, please contact the system administrator.

so i went into server log which shows :

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/myfolder/var/cache/prod/middlewares.cache.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/myfolder/app/middlewares/MiddlewareBuilder.php on line 82PHP message: PHP Warning - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - in file /var/www/mauticwp/app/middlewares/MiddlewareBuilder.php - at line 84PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/mauticwp/app/middlewares/MiddlewareBuilder.php on line 84PHP message: RuntimeException: Unable to create the "cache" directory (/var/www/myfolder/var/cache/prod). - in file /var/www/myfolder/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php - at line 765'

```
    #NameVirtualHost *:8000
<VirtualHost *:8000>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName somesubdomain.mydomains.com
        ServerAlias www.somesubdomain.mydomains.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/some_directory
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId mauticadmin www-data
    </IfModule>


        <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
                AddHandler php7.4-fcgi .php
                Action php7.4-fcgi /php7.4-fcgi virtual
                Alias /php7.4-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.4-fcgi-somesubdomain.mydomains.com
                FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.4-fcgi-test.com -socket /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm-mautic.ndedges.com.sock -pass-header Authorization
        </IfModule>
     <Directory /var/www/some_directory>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

    <FilesMatch .php$>
        # 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
         SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

within fpm/pool.d/www.mautic.conf. i added

```
    php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
```

as I have multiple PHP in the same server. I have Cloudflare configured within WordPress and redirects to HTTPS. but i am unable to use ip and port to use it.

I am completely clueless about what could be the reason.

thx

Comment: `Failed opening` indicates that either the file doesn't exist or your web server process doesn't have permission to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time it is Cache and Permission related Issue, In my opinion It has nothing to do with Apache configuration.

- Use `ps aux` to identify which user owns the apache process,
- Mostly it is `www-data`,
- Make sure to chown on all directories and sub directories to change ownership to `www-data`.
- Make sure files and directories have proper permissions for `www-data`, Mautic needs write access to Media, var/cache and var/logs directories.

https://tutorialsjoint.com/install-mautic/ in this tutorial checkout the section "Setting rights and permissions for Mautic Installation".

It'll work the same weather it is nginx or apache as this problem seems to be linux related only.

Comment: is no way to configure it to suppress subdomain.domain.com:port here? i think we need a proxy to that. within cloudflare there is spectrum but for apache2 we may use proxy . but can you explain the process?

Comment: I am not sure about proxy on apache2 but we can definitely place an nginx in front and use it as reverse proxy. https://github.com/stollz/MauticSSLDocker try this one, and there are some similar packages as well. if it doesn't work directly, perhaps you can use the parent package or reconfigure the docker compose to suit your requirement

Comment: hi, i think Nginx is not the best practice. best practice will be simply either squid or clouflare spectrum. but if you want to get the job done(for personal purpose) mod_proxy for windows or proxy will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

i also find some error

```
 [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1440453] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mpm-itk/2.4.7-04 OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
```

> <FilesMatch ".php$"> # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
> SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"

this one did the job. i removed that fpm configuration but it works like a charm. actually, the same settings did not work for him but it worked for me.

ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317077/apache-sethandler-not-working-with-multiple-php-version

maybe due to the apache2 version. but it has a different problem now i can access it through elastic ip and non SSL port but not with the A record.

now mautic is set with SES but i need to set a bounce endpoint with sns topic. and set a cronjob as www-data.

Comment: To set cronjob as www-data you can use `crontab -u www-data -e`

Comment: hi i would love to do that but it will use php version 8 not php version 7.4. i tried to set path but it was still holding php v8.0. i need a work aroud so that during cron operation it use php 7.4 not php 8.0.

Comment: Did you try giving full path to php binary ? I use ubuntu and I am able to do `/bin/php8.0 -v` to get output from php 8.0 while in global configuration I use php 7.4, so opposite must be true as well, even though you use PHP8.0 you should be able to do `/bin/php7.4`.

so in your cron 
try 
`x * * * * /bin/php7.4 /path/to/mautic/bin/console mautic:campaign:trigger` or however you would like to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access with the IP not using the SSL of Cloudflare proxied A record because it doesn't support other than these ports to trust support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/… Cloudflare only accept these ports nothing else. After changing those it was immediately turned into grey and secured. –

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/subdomains-are-not-getting-redirected-to-themselves/279745